# Java FX TextArea ScrollLeft Precision with Backspace

Tags: java, javafx-2

In the TextArea widget of Java FX 2.2, the method *getScrollLeft* is described in the documentation as returning

> The number of pixels by which the content is horizontally scrolled.

More precisely, it accesses the value of the property ScrollLeft which has the above description.

When I slide either the horizontal or vertical scrollbar, this variable is adjusted, as expected. **However** when I press "**backspace**" on a line that is longer than the screen width such that the scroll amount decreases, or at the first character of a row, the property is **not** adjusted even though the scroll position changes.

A hacky way to fix this is to access the scrollbar directly, get how much of it is being scrolled, and calculate the appropriate value based on that information. I'd prefer not to do this.

Is there an accepted way to solve this problem, or am I misusing the scrollbar information?

Comment: How about when backspace is pressed, you change the caret position ?

Comment: The caret decrements as expected when backspace is pressed, the scrollLeft property just isn't updating; what should I change the caret position to?

Comment: And why is your text going off the screen ? I cant grasp it

Comment: It's pretty simple: let's say the TextArea has a width of 500 px; after ~42 characters at size 12 font the characters are going to extend out of the TextArea. If text wrapping isn't on, then a scrollbar will appear at the bottom; the scroll value of this scrollbar, accessed through getScrollLeft of the TextArea, is not updated when I click backspace. It is for any other key, manually scrolling, and every other action I've tried